# Direct Traffic to a Kubernetes Pod Based on Initial Connection

Tags: kubernetes, istio, stateful

I'd like to direct traffic from a load balancer within Kubernetes to a deployment.  However, rather than attempting to achieve a uniform load across all pods of a deployment, I'd like each connection to and maintain a connection to a specific pod.  I'll be sending GRPC requests to a stateful instance on the pod and it's critical that the client's GRPC requests are not sent to other pods.

My current implementation is probably needlessly complex.  Here's the pseudocode:

1. Cluster initialized with a custom python scheduler.
2. Several pods with the stateful application are created, each with a node port service and unique node port.
3. Client talks to the python scheduler using a socket interface and is assigned a port.
4. Client talks to the pod using the assigned nodeport.
5. Client (or the scheduler) terminates the pod.

I'm limited by the number of ports and am unable to direct traffic using AKS due to their node port limitations.  Additionally, though the advantage of the scheduler is the client can request pods of varying resources, but it's too much to test and maintain.

Is there a better solution to direct external traffic to individual stateful pods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default iptables service proxy implementation uses a very simple randomized round-robin algorithm for selecting which pod to use. If you use the IPVS implementation instead that does offer a lot more options, though that is unlikely to be an option on a hosted provider like AKS. So that would leave you with using a userspace proxy that supports gRPC like Traefik or Istio Ingress. Picking one is out of scope for SO but most of those proxies support some kind of connection stickiness of some form.

Answer (score 2):

This might be considered an anti-pattern, but this ended up being the occam's razor we needed to get our cluster off the ground.

The python scheduler was greatly simplified to create a new pod whenever a client requested a instance of our application.  The scheduler waited until the application was running (by querying the pod), and then gave the client the ip address of the pod itself.  Since our application is being accessed by a jupyterhub cluster on the same network on Azure, we can see the pod since we're using Azure CNI networking.

No, we're not using a load balancer per-say, but this solution allows us to spawn pods of varying sizes (vcpu and ram) at the request of a user.  Additionally, if a pod can't be requested, the Python scheduler can send a helpful message to the user (e.g. insufficient available RAM/CPU).

While this isn't utilizing kubernetes load balancing, we don't need load balancing, we need n-scalable isolated containers with variable resource allocations.  Kubernetes is great at spawning the pods, and with a custom python scheduler, it's easy to get the IP address of those pods and terminate them when necessary (by spawning a thread within the scheduler whenever a pod is created).

I still think coderanger has the most "kubernetes" answer, but maybe this solution is an option as well for those who don't want to investigate additional kubernetes frameworks.

If anyone's interested, here's a sterilized version of the Scheduler:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
"""
"""
import signal
import socket
import urllib3
from threading import Timer
import tarfile
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
import logging
import re
import yaml
import time
import threading
import os
import random
import string
from threading import Thread
from urllib3.exceptions import ProtocolError
import argparse

from kubernetes import client, config, watch, utils
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
from kubernetes.stream import stream
from kubernetes import watch

NAME_MASKED_PORT_NAME = 'name_masked-port'
NAMESPACE = 'name_masked'
NAME_MASKED_GRPC_PORT = 49999
SERVER_PORT = 29999
DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 3600  # kill jobs that run longer than this
DEFAULT_KEEP_RESERVE = False
STORAGE_SECRET_NAME = 'storage-secret'

# in NCPU
DEFAULT_CPU_REQUEST = 0.5
DEFAULT_CPU_LIMIT = 1

# in GB
DEFAULT_RAM_REQUEST = 1
DEFAULT_RAM_LIMIT = 2


# InsecureRequestWarning
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOG.setLevel('DEBUG')


def threaded(fn):
    """ calls a function using a thread """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.daemon = kwargs.pop('daemon', True)
        thread.start()
        return thread
    return wrapper


def decode_request(request):
    # expect request to be formatted as
    # '{n_cpu_request}, {ram_request}, {n_cpu_limit}, {ram_limit}, {command}, {instance_timeout} {assign_port}'

    request.decode()
    LOG.debug('Received client request %s', request)
    n_cpu_request, ram_request, n_cpu_limit, ram_limit, command, pod_timeout, _ = eval(request)

    # command may be formated as a "None" string
    if command == "None":
        command = None

    return n_cpu_request, ram_request, n_cpu_limit, ram_limit, command, pod_timeout


def random_string(stringLength=10):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))


NAME_MASKED_IMAGE = 'name_maskedhelm.azurecr.io/name_masked_lite:v0.1'
IMAGE_SECRET_NAME = 'containersecret'

# using MPI
LAUNCH_NAME_MASKED = '/company_inc/bin'

NFS_NAME_MASKED_VOLUME = {'name': 'nfs-name_masked-volume',
                     'nfs': {'server': '10.0.0.12',  # gobetween
                             'path': '/mnt/company_inc',
                             'readOnly': True}}

NAME_MASKED_NFS_CONTAINER = {
    'name': 'name_masked-ctr',
    'image': NAME_MASKED_IMAGE,
    'command': ['/bin/sh',
                '-ec',
                LAUNCH_NAME_MASKED],
    'volumeMounts': [{'name': 'nfs-name_masked-volume', 'mountPath': '/company_inc'}],
    'resources': {'requests': {'cpu': '500m', 'memory': '512Mi'},
                  'limits': {'cpu': '1000m', 'memory': '1024Mi'}}}

SOMENAME_JOB_NFS = {
    'apiVersion': 'batch/v1',
    'kind': 'Job',
    'metadata': {'name': 'name_masked-UNNAMED',
                 'namespace': NAMESPACE},
    'spec': {'backoffLimit': 1,
             'template': {'spec': {'restartPolicy': 'Never',
                                   'backoffLimit': 1,
                                   'containers': [NAME_MASKED_NFS_CONTAINER],
                                   'imagePullSecrets': [{'name': IMAGE_SECRET_NAME}],
                                   'volumes': [NFS_NAME_MASKED_VOLUME]}}}
}

BASE_SOMENAME_POD = {
    'apiVersion': 'v1',
    'kind': 'Pod',
    'metadata': {'name': 'name_masked',
                 'namespace': NAMESPACE},
    'spec': {'restartPolicy': 'Never',
              'backoffLimit': 1,
              'containers': [NAME_MASKED_NFS_CONTAINER],
              'imagePullSecrets': [{'name': IMAGE_SECRET_NAME}],
              'volumes': [NFS_NAME_MASKED_VOLUME]}}

IMAGE_SECRET = {'apiVersion': 'v1',
                'type': 'kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson',
                'kind': 'Secret',
                'metadata' : {'name': IMAGE_SECRET_NAME,
                              'namespace': NAMESPACE},
                'data': {'.dockerconfigjson': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx'}
}

# above secret is created with:
# kubectl create secret docker-registry containersecret --docker-server=name_maskedhelm.azurecr.io --docker-username=name_maskedhelm --docker-password=IZUV0FI/XXXzove9KLa7FOvikO6eKFLt --docker-email=name@company.com --namespace name_masked



def open_logger(loglevel='DEBUG'):
    """ Opens a log """
    # don't add another handler if log has already been initialized
    if hasattr(open_logger, 'log'):
        open_logger.log.handlers[0].setLevel(loglevel.upper())
    else:
        log = logging.getLogger()
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(loglevel.upper())

        formatstr = '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s'
        ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(formatstr))
        log.addHandler(ch)
        open_logger.log = log
    return open_logger.log


class PodScheduler():
    """Pod scheduler"""

    def __init__(self, log_level='DEBUG',
                 reserve_target=4,
                 clear_on_init=False,
                 server_port=SERVER_PORT,
                 block=True,
                 instance_timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
                 image=None,
                 default_cpu_request=DEFAULT_CPU_REQUEST,
                 default_cpu_limit=DEFAULT_CPU_LIMIT,
                 default_ram_request=DEFAULT_RAM_REQUEST,
                 default_ram_limit=DEFAULT_RAM_LIMIT,
                 keep_reserve=DEFAULT_KEEP_RESERVE,
                 clear_on_exit=True):
        """Initialize job controller"""
        open_logger(log_level)
        self.deployment_name = None
        self._reserve_target = reserve_target
        self.enable_watch = True
        self._active = True
        self._events = []
        self._server_port = server_port
        self._server = None
        self._clear_on_exit = clear_on_exit
        # self._instance_state_locked = True
        self._assigned = {}
        self._pods = None
        self._terminate = False
        self._image = image
        self._purge_dangling_resources = False
        # self._job_count = 0
        # self._lock_count = False
        self._requested_pods = []
        self._timeouts = {}
        self._name_lock = False

        self._default_cpu_request = default_cpu_request
        self._default_cpu_limit = default_cpu_limit
        self._default_ram_request = default_ram_request
        self._default_ram_limit = default_ram_limit

        LOG.info('Default culling SOMENAME instances at %d seconds', instance_timeout)
        self._instance_timeout = instance_timeout

        # load credentials based on if running within a kubernetes pod
        if 'KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST' in os.environ:
            config.load_incluster_config()
        else:
            # config file must contain the correct IP address, cert, and admin password
            # copy from microk8s server with:
            # microk8s.kubectl config view --raw > $HOME/.kube/config
            path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
            config.load_kube_config(os.path.join(path, 'config'))

            configuration = client.Configuration()
            configuration.verify_ssl = False  # necessary for microk8s
            client.Configuration.set_default(configuration)

        # connect to kubernetes api
        self.core_api = client.CoreV1Api()

        # create name_masked namespace if it doesn't exist
        self.create_namespace(NAMESPACE)

        # add secrets
        self._add_image_secret()

        if clear_on_init:
            LOG.info('Clearing on initialization')
            self.clear()

        # start port assignment thread
        self.start_port_server()

        if block:
            self.block_execution()


    def _add_image_secret(self):
        """Initialize Azure container resource secret"""
        if IMAGE_SECRET_NAME not in self.secret_names:
            self.core_api.create_namespaced_secret(NAMESPACE, IMAGE_SECRET)
            LOG.info(f'Added image secret "{IMAGE_SECRET_NAME}"')
        else:
            LOG.info(f'Secret "{IMAGE_SECRET_NAME}" already exists')

    def _remove_image_secret(self):
        """Remove Azure container resource secret"""
        if IMAGE_SECRET_NAME in self.secret_names:
            response = self.core_api.delete_namespaced_secret(IMAGE_SECRET_NAME,
                                                              NAMESPACE)
            LOG.info(f'Removed image secret "{IMAGE_SECRET_NAME}"')

    @property
    def secret_names(self):
        secret_names = []
        for secret in self.secrets:
            secret_names.append(secret.metadata.name)
        return secret_names

    @property
    def secrets(self):
        """NAME_MASKED namespace secrets"""
        return self.core_api.list_namespaced_secret(NAMESPACE).items

    def clear(self):
        """Delete all services, jobs, and pods in the 'name_masked' namespace"""
        # self.delete_all_services()
        # self.delete_all_jobs()
        self.delete_all_pods()
        # self._instances = {}

    @property
    def pods(self):
        """Name_Masked pods"""
        self._pods = self.core_api.list_namespaced_pod(NAMESPACE).items
        return self._pods

    @property
    def active_pods(self):
        """running pods"""
        active_pods = []
        for pod in self.pods:
            status = pod.status
            metadata = pod.metadata

            if status.container_statuses:
                container_status = status.container_statuses[0]
                if hasattr(container_status, 'ready'):
                    if container_status.ready:
                        active_pods.append(metadata.name)

        return active_pods

    def delete_all_pods(self):
        """Delete all jobs"""
        for pod in self.pods:
            self.delete_pod(pod.metadata.name)

    def delete_pod(self, pod_name):
        """Delete a NAME_MASKED namespaced pod"""
        try:
            self.core_api.delete_namespaced_pod(pod_name, NAMESPACE)
            LOG.info(f'Deleted pod {pod_name}')
        except ApiException:
            LOG.error(f'Unable to delete pod {pod_name}')

    def _wait_for_pod(self, pod_name, timeout=20):
        """Returns pod yaml when pod is ready.  Otherwise, raises an exception"""
        tstart = time.time()
        while (time.time() - tstart) < timeout:
            time.sleep(0.5)

            pod = self.core_api.read_namespaced_pod(pod_name, NAMESPACE)
            status = pod.status
            metadata = pod.metadata

            if status.conditions:
                if status.conditions[0].reason == 'Unschedulable':
                    reason = status.conditions[0].message
                    raise RuntimeError(f'Unable to create pod: {reason}')

            if status.container_statuses:
                container_status = status.container_statuses[0]
                if hasattr(container_status, 'ready'):
                    if container_status.ready:
                        return pod
                if hasattr(container_status, 'state'):
                    if container_status.state.terminated:
                        if hasattr(container_status.state.terminated, 'exit_code'):
                            if container_status.state.terminated.exit_code:
                                reason = container_status.state.terminated.reason
                                raise RuntimeError(f'Unable to create pod: {reason}')

                if hasattr(container_status.state, 'waiting'):
                    if container_status.state.waiting is not None:
                        reason = container_status.state.waiting.message
                        if reason is not None:
                            raise RuntimeError(f'Unable to create pod: {reason}')

        raise RuntimeError(f'TIMEOUT at {timeout} seconds:\nUnable to create pod: Logs:\n {pod}')

    def _build_pod_yaml(self, cpu_request=None, ram_request=None,
                        cpu_limit=None, ram_limit=None, custom_command=None):
        """Build a job body"""
        # copy job yaml and modify it
        pod_name = self._assign_pod_name()
        pod_yaml = dict(BASE_SOMENAME_POD)
        pod_yaml['metadata']['name'] = pod_name        

        if cpu_request is None:
            cpu_request = self._default_cpu_request
        if cpu_limit is None:
            cpu_limit = self._default_cpu_limit
        if ram_request is None:
            ram_request = self._default_ram_request
        if ram_limit is None:
            ram_limit = self._default_ram_limit

        container = pod_yaml['spec']['containers'][0]
        limits = container['resources']['limits']
        requests = container['resources']['requests']

        limits['cpu'] = '%.2f' % float(cpu_limit)
        limits['memory'] = '%.2fGi' % float(ram_limit)

        requests['cpu'] = '%.2f' % float(cpu_request)
        requests['memory'] = '%.2fGi' % float(ram_request)

        LOG.info(f'Pod "{pod_name}" requested with:')
        LOG.info(f'Requests: {requests}')
        LOG.info(f'Limits: {limits}')

        # configure name_masked number of CPUs
        if custom_command is not None:
            command = custom_command
        else:
            command = LAUNCH_NAME_MASKED.replace('-grpc', '-np %d -grpc' % int(cpu_limit))

        LOG.info(f'Launching NAME_MASKED with "{command}"')
        container['command'][-1] = command
        return pod_yaml

    def _spawn_pod(self, pod_yaml):
        """Initialize pod and return the pod name"""
        # multiple attepts to create job due to potential naming conflicts
        resp = None
        pod_name = pod_yaml['metadata']['name']
        while resp is None:
            try:
                resp = self.core_api.create_namespaced_pod(NAMESPACE, pod_yaml)
            except Exception as exception:
                # sometimes a there's a conflict with the job name 
                # due to multiple simultaneous requests
                if 'AlreadyExists' in str(exception):
                    pod_name = self._assign_pod_name()
                    pod_yaml['metadata']['name'] = pod_name
                else:
                    raise exception

        # might have changed
        return pod_name

    def create_name_masked_pod(self, cpu_request=None, ram_request=None,
                   cpu_limit=None, ram_limit=None, timeout=120,
                   custom_command=None, pod_timeout=None):
        """Create a name_masked pod"""
        pod_yaml = self._build_pod_yaml(cpu_request, ram_request,
                                        cpu_limit, ram_limit, custom_command)
        pod_name = self._spawn_pod(pod_yaml)

        # set pod timeout countdown thread
        self._kill_pod_timeout(pod_name, pod_timeout)

        # wait until a pod is created
        try:
            pod = self._wait_for_pod(pod_name)
        except Exception as e:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.delete_pod(pod_name)
            raise Exception(e)

        return pod

    def _assign_pod_name(self):
        """Generates a unique pod name"""
        while self._name_lock:
            time.sleep(0.001)

        self._name_lock = True
        pod_name = 'name_masked-%s' % random_string(10)
        while pod_name in self._requested_pods:
            pod_name = 'name_masked-%s' % random_string(10)
        self._requested_pods.append(pod_name)

        self._name_lock = False
        return pod_name

    @threaded
    def _kill_pod_timeout(self, pod_name, pod_timeout=None):
        """Kill a pod once a timeout has been exceeded"""
        if pod_timeout is None:
            pod_timeout = self._instance_timeout
        elif pod_timeout > 86400:  # ensure pod timeouts cannot exceed 1 day
            pod_timeout = 86400
        elif pod_timeout < 20:  # minimum 20 seconds
            pod_timeout = 20

        LOG.info(f'Configured timeout for {pod_name} to {pod_timeout} seconds')
        time.sleep(pod_timeout)
        LOG.info(f'Triggered timeout for {pod_name} exceeded instance timeout ' +
                 f'of {pod_timeout} seconds')
        self.delete_pod(pod_name)

    def create_namespace(self, namespace):
        """Creates a namespace"""
        namespace_yaml = {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "Namespace",
            "metadata": {
                "name": namespace,
                "labels": {
                    "name": namespace
                }
            }
        }

        namespace_exists = False
        for _namespace in self.namespaces:
            if namespace == _namespace.metadata.name:
                namespace_exists = True
                break

        if not namespace_exists:
            response = self.core_api.create_namespace(namespace_yaml)
            LOG.debug(f'Created namespace "{namespace}"')
        else:
            LOG.debug(f'Namespace "{namespace}" exists')

    @property
    def namespaces(self):
        """cluster namespaces"""
        return self.core_api.list_namespace().items

    @threaded
    def _assign_client(self, client):
        """Receives a request from a client and returns an ip address
        """
        while True: 
            # data received from client
            request = client.recv(1024)
            if not request:
                break

            cpu_request, ram_request, cpu_limit, ram_limit, command, pod_timeout = decode_request(request)

            try:
                # assign a port
                pod = self.create_name_masked_pod(cpu_request=cpu_request,
                                            ram_request=ram_request,
                                            cpu_limit=cpu_limit,
                                            ram_limit=ram_limit,
                                            custom_command=command,
                                            pod_timeout=pod_timeout)

                # ip is the pod ip
                ip = pod.status.pod_ip
                port = 49999
                message = f'{ip}:{port}'
                client.send(message.encode())

            except Exception as e:
                message = 'EXCEPTION: %s' % str(e)
                client.send(message.encode())

        client.close()

    @threaded
    def start_port_server(self):
        """accepts incoming connections on _server_port and returns a port"""
        self._server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
        self._server.bind(("", self._server_port)) 

        # put the socket into listening mode 
        self._server.listen(5)
        LOG.info(f'Listening on port {self._server_port}')

        # listen indefinitely for new clients
        while True:
            # establish connection with client 
            client, addr = self._server.accept()
            LOG.info('Opening connection from %s:%s', str(addr[0]), str(addr[1]))
            self._assign_client(client)

    def block_execution(self):
        """Main thread to stop python from exiting.

        This instance can be exited gracefully in two ways:
        - With Ctrl-c
        - With SIGTERM

        """
        def received_sigterm(*args):
            """Handles SIGTERM"""
            LOG.info('Received SIGTERM')
            self._terminate = True

        # listen for sigterm
        LOG.info('PID: %d' % os.getpid())
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, received_sigterm)

        LOG.debug('Blocking execution.  Press Ctrl-c to open breakpoint')
        # user_break = False
        while not self._terminate:
            try:
                time.sleep(0.1)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                # user_break = True
                resp = input('Break? [Y/n]').lower()
                if resp == '' or resp == 'y':
                    break

        LOG.info('Deleting all NAME_MASKED jobs and pods due to clear_on_exit=True')
        if self._clear_on_exit:
            self.clear()

        self._close_server()

    def __del__(self):
        self._close_server()

    def exit(self, clear_jobs=True):
        """Clear jobs and close server"""
        if clear_jobs:
            self.clear()
        self._close_server()

    def _close_server(self):
        """Close connection to server"""
        if self._server is not None:
            self._server.close()
            LOG.info(f'Closed server on port {self._server_port}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ Supports calling gui directly with command line arguments """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='name_masked job controller')

    # parser.add_argument('-loglevel', metavar='DEBUG', type=str,
    #                     required=False, default='DEBUG',
    #                     help='Log level to use (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR)')

    parser.add_argument('-timeout', type=str, metavar='',
                        required=False,
                        help='timeout in seconds for interactive name_masked sessions')

    parser.add_argument('-default_cpu_request', type=str, metavar='',
                        required=False,
                        help='Number of cpus to request')

    parser.add_argument('-default_cpu_limit', type=str, metavar='',
                        required=False,
                        help='Number of cpus to limit to')

    parser.add_argument('-default_ram_request', type=str, metavar='',
                        required=False,
                        help='RAM request in GB')

    parser.add_argument('-default_ram_limit', type=str, metavar='',
                        required=False,
                        help='RAM limit in GB')

    parser.add_argument('--keep_reserve',
                        help='Keep a minimum number of name_masked instances on reserve',
                        action="store_true")


    args = parser.parse_args()

    script = None

    if args.default_cpu_request:
        default_cpu_request = args.default_cpu_request
    else:
        default_cpu_request = DEFAULT_CPU_REQUEST

    if args.default_cpu_limit:
        default_cpu_limit = args.default_cpu_limit
    else:
        default_cpu_limit = DEFAULT_CPU_LIMIT

    if args.default_ram_request:
        default_ram_request = args.default_ram_request
    else:
        default_ram_request = DEFAULT_RAM_REQUEST

    if args.default_ram_limit:
        default_ram_limit = args.default_ram_limit
    else:
        default_ram_limit = DEFAULT_RAM_LIMIT

    if args.keep_reserve:
        keep_reserve = args.keep_reserve
    else:
        keep_reserve = DEFAULT_KEEP_RESERVE

    # default timeout of one hour
    if args.timeout:
        timeout = int(args.timeout)
    else:
        timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT

    PodScheduler(clear_on_init=False,
                  log_level='INFO',
                  instance_timeout=timeout,
                  keep_reserve=keep_reserve,
                  default_cpu_request=default_cpu_request,
                  default_cpu_limit=default_cpu_limit,
                  default_ram_request=default_ram_request,
                  default_ram_limit=default_ram_limit)
```